# Drill Through Between Pages New Power Bi

Tags: powerbi

Before the last update that changed BI environment, I can make drill through between pages using the field that said: 'Add drill-through field here'

image here:
[image]

In the current version of BI, I can't find this field where I can put the value which I can zoom in from another page.

where is it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's moved with the introduction of On-Object Interaction.

[image]

[On-Object Interaction - Drillthrough and Tooltip Page Setup](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/on-object-public-preview-opt-in/#_Other_functional_changes)

GIAC did a view on that [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYxRHJ0hB_E).

You can also turn off the preview of On-Object Interaction:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! it is exactly the answer I needed.I did check on youtube but I missed that video.